# How do i get latest record of every set of records in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

My collection contain the following records.

```
{
    "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890a",
    "code" : 1,
    "datetime":"2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "balance" : 2000
}

{
    "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890b",
    "code" : 2,
    "datetime":"2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "balance" : 3000
}

{
    "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890c",
    "code" : 1,
    "datetime":"2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "balance" : 3000
}

{
    "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890d",
    "code" : 1,
    "datetime":"2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "balance" : 4000
}

{
    "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890e",
    "code" : 2,
    "datetime":"2017-01-05T00:00:00.000Z",
    "balance" : 7000
}

{
    "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890f",
    "code" : 1,
    "datetime":"2017-01-06T00:00:00.000Z",
    "balance" : 6000
}
```

I am making set of records based on code. As per above records there is only 2 sets code:1 and code:2.

So i want following output as latest record of code1 and code2

```
{ "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890f", "code" : 1,"datetime":"2017-01-06T00:00:00.000Z", "balance" : 6000 }

{ "_id" : "58a53f4aca3d39bcf9c3890e", "code" : 2,"datetime":"2017-01-05T00:00:00.000Z", "balance" : 7000 }
```

So how can i make query which will give me above output.?

Comment: you need ta add a date field to achieve this, otherwise you won't be able to know which documents are the latest

Comment: @felix Yes i have datetime field in every record, then how can i get that output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation of MongoDB,

**Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result**

As a solution to above mentioned problem please try executing following query

```
 db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
              _id:{code:'$code'},
              doc:{ "$last": "$$ROOT" }

            }
        },

    ]

);
```